# Objective C: How to get values of selected UIPickerView from one class to another

Tags: objective-c, datasource, uipickerview

I set the UIPickerView value in one class, implemented the delegate and everything else, and also `didSelectRow`.

In another ViewController of another class, I set the delegate for `dataSource`. But, when I try to call it, it is `null`.

How can this issue be fixed? I appreciate your help.

Code in `didSelectRow`:

```
    NSInteger distRow = [self.distPicker selectedRowInComponent: 
        pickerViewComponent];

    NSString *distance = self.dist[distRow];
```

I'm calling both of following methods from another `ViewController`, but it doesn't work:

```
    NSString *distance = self.dist[[self.distPicker selectedRowInComponent:
        pickerViewComponent]];

    NSLog(@"picker %@",self.distPicker.dataSource);
    NSLog(@"%@", distance);
```

`NSLong` for the picker is `null` and for time is `0`.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have a shared model between both classes.

Comment: So you want one class to be the delegate and another to be the data source or?

Comment: I want to use the selected pickerview items to be used in another class, I am not sure how to set it up

Comment: Why not have a property to pickerview items so you can access it from another class